# Running byebug with Heroku Local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, testing

I'm trying to run byebug so that it works with Heroku Local.

By default, the breakpoints don't give me access to an irb console like they might if I was using `rails s`.  I tried byebug's remote debugging as described here but something about running the byebug server slows my local server down to a crawl and it's unusable.  Is there anyway to get byebug to work with Heroku Local?  Is there any alternative debugging solution that works well for Rails and Heroku Local?

Comment: I'm talking about heroku local which is the heroku toolbelt command for running a local server that emulates the heroku environment.

Comment: ah I see, sorry I misunderstood.

Comment: [pry docs](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Setting-up-Rails-or-Heroku-to-use-Pry#heroku) has a section on Heroku, it's worth a shot and is a better debugger imo especially if you use the [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug) gem too, because pry has coloring and lets you run `show-source`.